# How to stop authentication while accessing Provider Hosted APP and Create SSO for APP?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, app

I have to setup provider hosted app to client side. I have to enter two time credentials while accessing app. First Time SharePoint Page and Second time while accessing APP.

Any SSO possible for same.

I am hosting APP on on-premise and Installing APP on on-premise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of authentication is on your on-premise SharePoint web application, where you are going to use your app?

Comment: Hi Kai, I am using windows authentication. I am using in SharePoint Site as a  SharePoint Page (App Part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, to make it work under IE, you need to put your app domain and SharePoint domain into the IE local Intranet zone:

[image]

Also make sure that automatic authentication is enabled:

[image]

Please, take a note, that this approach will work only if the user is inside organization domain, for outside the user will still be prompted for credentials. If you want to implement fully SSO, then you need to go with ADFS, this approach requires ADFS configuration inside SharePoint and changes in your app in order to support ADFS SSO.

For other browsers that might be harder. You can try to search for "integrated windows authentication" plugins for Chrome or Firefox.

IE settings can be pushed to the users via domain polices, but for other browsers every user need to manually download and install plugins.

Comment: Hi Kai, 

Thanks for your answer.

I need to do ADFS Configuration. May I have steps or link for same to ADFS SSO Configuration.


Nice approach you have given thanks.

Comment: There are plenty resources available for ADFS confguring, for example [this one from msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx) or [detailed on third party site](https://blogit.create.pt/miguelmoreno/2014/11/14/configure-adfs-3-0-with-sharepoint-2013/). For ADFS with provider apps consider this article from Wictor Willen - [SharePoint 2013 with SAML Claims and Provider Hosted Apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-provider-hosted-apps)